# Jupiter disk exceeded quota

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupiter notebook on a cloud server and after running many iterations and saving my data I encountered the error exceeded disk quota and when I try to remove some file I get failed, do yo know how can I access the trash or free some space ? I found a file share but there is no trash inside

And if there is another file or folder I can delete to free some space

Comment: You need more details, or question will be closed. Cloud product, what have you tried? Specific errors and commands.

Comment: I got error of 122 disk quota exceeded, and it's a jupyter working space , where I saved my pickle files and the storage is full now so I am looking for a way to free some space or force the delete of my files

Comment: Im sorry but the information is very vague and not specific of what you have tried, CLI outputs, etc. I vote for closing until you provide a better problem description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask